# Vim/Vi Select visual select inside macro

Tags: vim, vi, vsvim

I would like to create a macro to replace having to type:

```
vi(
vi[
vi"
```

etc.

I have been trying things along the line of:

```
:nnoremap <leader><tab> vy:exe vi"0<cr>
```

but not succeeding.

I'm on Windows using VsVim.

Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly ?

Comment: Have a single macro that will select text inside " " [ ] ( ) { } when the cursor is on the opening character.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried adding this to my `_vsvimrc`:

`nnoremap gP vi"`

and it worked just fine, as far as I could see. Does this give you what you need?

Comment: no that only works to select inside " ". The macro I'm trying to create works for any enclosing characters.

Something like this, although it seems that a registry character does not work with the vi command in vsvim.


    :nnoremap<leader>t vy:execute "normal! vi<c-r><c-w> "<CR>

Comment: Why not use `v%` then? Solves most of those cases, perhaps not quotes, though.

Answer (score 0):

In Vim, you can do this:

```
:nnoremap <leader><tab> yl:execute 'normal! vi' . @"<CR>
```

This `y`anks the character under the cursor, and then uses `:normal!` to run the `vi...` normal mode command, and `:execute` to interpolate the register contents into it.

I don't know about VsVim's capabilities, but I doubt it offers these capabilities; you can probably only do simple vi-style mappings there.